# Use react-helmet with renderToNodeStream

Tags: reactjs, microdata, server-side-rendering, node-streams, react-helmet

On a website - React with SSR using renderToNodeStream() - I use React-Helmet to inject appropriate microdata in the head (ld+json script tag) when navigating client-side (not sure if useful for the SEO), and on the server I 'trick' the fact that helmet is not supposed to work with renderToNodeStream as follows:

### client:

(autobinded method called on the render, not doing anything server-side)

```
head() {
    return (
        <Helmet>
            <script type="application/ld+json">
                {JSON.stringify(get***MicroData(this.props.***))}
            </script>
        </Helmet>
    );
}
```

### server:

```
oResponse.write(
    [
      `<html>`,
      `<head>`,
      (...)
      `<script type="application/ld+json" data-react-helmet="true">${getMicroData(***)}/script>`,
      (...)
      `</head>`,
    ].join(""),
);

(...)

const stream = ReactDOMServer[renderMethod](     // renderToNodeStream || renderToStaticNodeStream
    <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={sURL} context={context}>
            <RootContainer ***={***}/>
        </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>,
);
```

it seems to work fine, just wanted to make sure there's no issue with this piece of code.. (hydration)

thanks!